# SQL: COUNT PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working on forecasting items demand from a warehouse to a respective store. But in order to forecast I need to at least have 2 time series for every product from a warehouse to their respective store.

Currently I worked this:

```
SELECT t.date,t.Qty,t.ItemID,t.Warehouse,t.Store 
FROM(SELECT date,
Warehouse,
SUM(Qty),
ItemID,
Store,
Count (*) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID,Warehouse,Store ) as cnt 
FROM database 
GROUP BY date,Warehouse,ItemID,Store)t 
WHERE cnt >= 2 
ORDER BY t.date DESC;
```

Nevertheless the forecasting package that i'm using says there is an error because the dataframe has less than 2 non NA values to forecast. This is the part of the code that process the previous df.

```
d1 <- df %>% 
nest(-`Warehouse`,-`ItemID`,-`Store`)%>% 
mutate(m = map(data, prophet,algorithm='Newton')) %>%
mutate(future = map(m, make_future_dataframe,freq="week",periods=52)) %>%
mutate(forecast = map2(m, future, predict))
d <- d1 %>% 
unnest(forecast) %>% 
select(date,`Warehouse`, yhat,`ItemID`,`Store`)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working". Do you get an error? Or if not, what are you getting compared to what you want to get?

Comment: whats your requirement post table as text and explain it clearly!!

Comment: @DancingFool the forecasting package that i'm using says there is an error because the dataframe has less than 2 non NA values to forecast.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh the forecasting package that i'm using says there is an error because the dataframe has less than 2 non NA values to forecast.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your SQL - the forecasting package must be hiding it. Qty is in your subquery select statement, but it is not in the group by clause, and it is not being treated as an aggregate. You probably want to sum it, so your line with "Qty," should be "Sum(Qty) as Qty,". The total query would be

```
SELECT t.date,t.Qty,t.ItemID,t.Warehouse,t.Store 
FROM(SELECT date,
Warehouse,
SUM(Qty) as Qty,
ItemID,
Store,
Count (*) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID,Warehouse,Store ) as cnt 
FROM database 
GROUP BY date,Warehouse,ItemID,Store)t 
WHERE cnt >= 2 
ORDER BY t.date DESC;
```

---

UPDATED to add

This (fixed) SQL is only returning rows where there are at least two records for any Item/Warehouse/Store combo. However, it is not returning them together - it is sorting by date only. Maybe the forecast package expects all the rows for a particular combo to be together?  Try changing the ORDER BY line at the end to

```
ORDER BY t.ItemID, t.Warehouse, t.Store, t.date DESC;
```

Comment: You're right. I forgot to put the aggregation in the example, however, initially, already did on my code.

Comment: OK, if the aggregation is not the problem, then you're getting the right data, but maybe it's not how the forecast package expects?  I've added an update to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please add **Qty** in your group by clause.

Comment: This will resolve the error on his query I guess. So possibly it is the Answer.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to put the aggregation in the example, but I already did on my code.

Answer (score 0):

you mean to say that Forecasting Package  is throwing validation message.

no need of `Count window function` when you are already using `Group By` on all columns.

Also people are right here, that either include QTY in group By or use aggregate function on QTY.

And main error is not because of this.

If there is minor mistake then you can correct yourself.

```
SELECT t.date,t.Qty,t.ItemID,t.Warehouse,t.Store 
FROM(SELECT date,
Warehouse,
sum(Qty) Qty,
ItemID,
Store,
Count (*)  as cnt 
FROM database 
GROUP BY date,Warehouse,ItemID,Store)t 
WHERE cnt >= 2 
ORDER BY t.date DESC;
```

Or May Be you need to mention columname inside count to give accurate count.

```
Declare @t table(col int,col1 int)
insert into @t values(null,1),(1,2)

select count(*) from @t

or

select count(col) from @t
```